# changing a wildcard in an excel hyperlink with vba

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I would like some help with removing/replacing a wildcard character in an excel hyperlink. 
Logically it seems very easy but it's beyond my abilities.

I have a spreadsheet with hyperlinks to PDF documents. The hyperlinks contain the "#" character and that stops the file path from working.  In the hyperlink I simply need to change the "#" to "%23" and the link works.  I don't want to do this manually because of the amount of links.  Is there any way of achieving this with VBA.  It seems easy enough to change a file path but searching a hyperlink and changing the # doesn't seem to be possible.

All the hyperlinks are in column A.

Comment: Is the hyperlink in a Hyperlink() function or has it been manually inserted with Insert > Hyperlink?

Comment: Hi teylyn,  It's not a hyperlink function of the sheet as in it does not appear in the formula bar.  Right click > edit hyperlink is the only why to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel treats text to the left of the `#` as the `.Address` and to the right as the `.SubAddress` - as it suggests an anchor type link. You'd need to repair this on each link like so:

```
For Each lk In Sheets("YourSheetName").Range("A:A").Hyperlinks
    If lk.SubAddress <> "" Then
        lk.Address = lk.Address & "%23" & lk.SubAddress
        lk.SubAddress = ""
    End If
Next
```

Comment: 100% correct.  Nobody else has managed to come up with that.  Thank you